# How do I stop (not kill) an Activity to trigger an onRestart()?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm working on an Android application. Our problems manifest when the user runs our app, navigates away via the home or back button, and comes back later. From the official Android [activity lifecycle documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and Eric Burke's helpful reformatting of the [lifecycle diagram](http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/05/android-activity-lifecycle-updated/), I suspect that our activity is begin killed while stopped, but (critically) not destroyed.

In other words, from running, the functions called are `onPause(), onStop(), onRestart(), onStart()`, and `onResume()`. Note, importantly, that this means that `onRestart()` is being called in the middle instead of onCreate(), which would happen if the app were just killed and removed from memory. This, I think, is the problem.

That's the setup. Here's the question: is there any way that I can reliably force the application to be **stopped** so that I can reproduce this condition. I don't want to kill the app, and I don't want it to just be `paused`.

Is there an ADB command? DDMS? Something in the phone?

I've tried faking it by running other memory-hungry apps, but that always just leads it getting killed outright, which means the app gets started all over and onCreate is run and I don't learn anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any way that I can reliably force the application to be stopped so that I can reproduce this condition. I don't want to kill the app, and I don't want it to just be paused.

Press the HOME button.

Comment: And then restart it again by holding the HOME button and switching back to your app.

Comment: Won't this cause it to simply be paused? From reading the documentation, it won't be stopped until some of its memory is needed. This is consistent with our problems that some of our program data is being garbage collected, as though the program were being stopped. The problem only manifests after navigating away from the app for a while (that's as precise as I know to be) and come back.

Comment: @Hober: "Won't this cause it to simply be paused?" -- no, it will be stopped. "it won't be stopped until some of its memory is needed" -- no, that is when it is destroyed.